# Dirichlet Series of weakly multiplicative characters

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, dirichlet-series

Let
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n)n^{-s} = \prod_{p}\left((1-\alpha_{p}p^{-s})(1-\alpha_{p}'p^{-s})\right)^{-1},$$
where $ a(n) $ is weakly multiplicative (i.e $ a(n)a(m) = a(n,m) $ if $ \textit{gcd}(m,n) = 1 $). Then the claim is that
$$ a(p^{n}) = (\alpha_{p}^{n+1}-\alpha_{p}'^{n+1})/(\alpha_{p}-\alpha_{p}') $$ if $ \alpha_{p} \neq \alpha_{p}' $. My tepmtation is argue
$$ \sum_{1}^{\infty}a(n)n^{-s} = \prod_{p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(p^{n})p^{-ns} $$
and use the expansion of a geometric series. However as the intention is to use this result on Dirichlet series coming from an eigenform the $ a(p)^{n} \neq a(p^{n}) $, and furthermore it is not clear that $ |a(p)p^{-s}|<1 $. If anybody knows a proof or has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you call weakly multiplicative is usually just called multiplicative (and the stronger condition that $a(n)a(m) = a(nm)$ for all $m,n$ is called completely multiplicative or totally multiplicative).

Comment: Your idea is correct; the multiplicativity of $a(n)$ implies that it factors into an Euler product with each term in the product of the form $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a(p^n) p^{-ns}$. Now expand $(1 - \alpha_p p^{-s})^{-1}(1 - \alpha_p' p^{-s})^{-1}$ as a Taylor series in $p^{-s}$ and compare coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot that we only consider the $ L $-function of an eigenform for sufficently large $ s $ (i.e large enough to ensure $ a(n) < Cn^{-s} $ which sorts out the issue of $ |\alpha_{p}p^{-ns}|< 1$).